# Viewing data in entity framework core database

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am learning to use .net core and EF core. I would like to use a tool similar to Sql Management studio to view the data in my ef core db. Is there a tool to view the data in the database?

Comment: Entity Framework is a data access technology, not a database itself.  If you're using Entity Framework with SQL Server, you can continue to use Sql Management Studio.  Alternatively, check out linqpad.

Comment: Thanks Matt. I assumed EF core was a NoSql db similar to mongo db.